# WP8: Is there an easy way to scale and blur an BitmapImage for windows phone app?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, effect, bitmapimage

I am working on a windows Phone app that can read Album arts dynamically from Music files through MediaPlayer APIs. I wish to get album arts and resize for view's background. Since the resize would lose details and make image ugly so I would like to blur it or some kind of effect. Is there any API that I can blur the image? (either from C# or XAML)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would start by using WriteableBitmap instead, to get a WriteableBitmap from a BitmapImage you can do the following:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

Then I would recommend using the [WriteableBitmapExtension library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). It has support for resizing the image:

```
wb.Resize(newWidth, newHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```

To do the [gaussian blur](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/236374) with WritableBitmapExtensions do the following (for some reason concolution doesn't edit the writableBitmap, so you have to assign it again to the same writableBitmap to see the result):

```
wb = wb.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
```

or

```
wb = wb.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur3x3);
```

(Just different weights for the neighbouring pixels).

Comment: Hi, is this right way of doing it? It seems not working??    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(albumArtImage);</br>WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);</br>AlbumBackground.ImageSource = wb;
</code

Comment: For some reason the result of the convolution is not applied to wb, but returned instead, so you need to assign it to wb again, see the updated answer. (I tried it in WP7 emulator and it seems to work now.)

Comment: @Johan Falk WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage); only this line give me error when i am capture from camera. Please suggest.

Comment: @MayurBhola What's the error? Probably better to ask a new question for when capturing with the camera? I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: @JohanFalk I think its not new question, Having Outofmemory error when i am pick image from camera/gallery, Debug for the issue, it is exception when creating new WritableBitmap object from bitmapImage. Thanks for your replay.. looking forward for your answer.