# Windows Phone 8.1 image scaling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How i can show the image, that user can scale like in gallery? I meant scaling with two fingers and etc.
User cant resize simple < Image > object.

Comment: DId you try using the `WriteableBitmap`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927845/wp8-is-there-an-easy-way-to-scale-and-blur-an-bitmapimage-for-windows-phone-app
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Seems it impossible to use WriteabeBitmap in 8.1 like in [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927845/wp8-is-there-an-easy-way-to-scale-and-blur-an-bitmapimage-for-windows-phone-app). Its constructor is WriteableBitmap(int width, int height) only

Comment: WriteableBitmap works fine in WP8.1. What's wrong with the constructor only taking width/height as parameters? All WriteableBitmaps are 32-bpp BGRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled">
        <Image Source="myimage.jpg" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

You can also add ScrollViewer's `MinZoomFactor` and `MaxZoomFactor` (default values are 0,1 and 2)