# How we can use effects on an image in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to apply different effects like sharpen.Blur,Grayscale etc. on an image in windows phone 8. if i use Nokia Imaging Sdk then trere are some error related silverlight projects.Can Anyone please suggest How can i achieved that?

Answers will be really appreciated..

Comment: Refer to `Johan Falk's` answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927845/wp8-is-there-an-easy-way-to-scale-and-blur-an-bitmapimage-for-windows-phone-app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find this post as a good help [Starting with Nokia Imaging SDK](http://www.tozon.info/blog/post/2013/07/16/Starting-with-Nokia-Imaging-SDK.aspx) and to this post you would find [APPLYING NOKIA IMAGING SDK FILTERS ON IMAGE IN WINDOWS PHONE 8.](http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/applying-nokia-imaging-sdk-filters-on-image-in-windows-phone-8/) Try it out may it help you out.