# Add blur effect on image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i want blur effect on image on the potion which user tap.User can tap multiple times on image and when he taps the image potion which he taps get blur.

```
using (var blurfilters = new FilterEffect(source))
{
    var blur = new BlurFilter();

    blurfilters.Filters = new IFilter[] { blur };
    var target = new WriteableBitmap((int)img1.ActualWidth, (int)img1.ActualHeight);
    using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(blurfilters, target))
    {
        await renderer.RenderAsync();
        img1.Source = target;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this One:

```
var blur = new BlurFilter(30);
```

Edit :

To do the [gaussian blur](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/236374) with WritableBitmapExtensions do the following (for some reason concolution doesn't edit the writableBitmap, so you have to assign it again to the same writableBitmap to see the result):

```
WriteableBitmap target = new WriteableBitmap((int)img1.ActualWidth, (int)img1.ActualHeight);
target = target.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
```

or

```
target = target.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur3x3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/1/29/implementing-image-blur-in-a-windows-universal-app

This worked for me for an universal app.

The effective code is:

```
private void OnDraw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    if (imageLoaded)
    {
        using (var session = args.DrawingSession)
        {
            session.Units = CanvasUnits.Pixels;

            double displayScaling = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi / 96.0;

            double pixelWidth = sender.ActualWidth * displayScaling;

            var scalefactor = pixelWidth / image.Size.Width;

            scaleEffect.Source = this.image;
            scaleEffect.Scale = new Vector2()
            {
                X = (float)scalefactor,
                Y = (float)scalefactor
            };

            blurEffect.Source = scaleEffect;
            blurEffect.BlurAmount = Blur;

            session.DrawImage(blurEffect, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

For Silverlight app try this one :

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1033

Another good example if you wish Gaussian blur is:

[WP8: Is there an easy way to scale and blur an BitmapImage for windows phone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927845/wp8-is-there-an-easy-way-to-scale-and-blur-an-bitmapimage-for-windows-phone-app)

Comment: i want to blur that portion of image on which i tap.

Comment: adjust the canvas accordingly. If you are using XAML WinRT app, not a silverlight one.

Comment: plzz tell me that how can i select the desired region which i want to blur on tap